# How to push to a list in an Asynchronous Task and return the list only after the async task is finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am having problem returning a list.  First, I add element to the list from querying the database and once the DB querying is finished then only I return the list.  But, I realized that querying is happening asynchronously and this code is returning before it has finished querying all the datas and adding it to the list.

I know in other languages, we could've used Mutex or Semaphore to solve this issue of race conditions but How can we deal with this in Javascript?

```
    let all_recipe= []
        for(let i =0; i<result.chefs.email.length; ++i)
        {

            chefSchema['chef'].findOne({"email":result.chefs.email[i]},"recipe")
            .then(recipes=>{
                if(recipes!=null)
                {

                    if(recipes.recipe.length!=0)
                    {
                        all_recipe.push(recipes.recipe);
                    }

                }
                            console.log("Async Test1")
            }).catch(err=>
            {

                console.log(err);
                return res.status(500).json({
                    message:"Finding Chef Database Error!",
                    error: err
                });
            });

        }
        console.log("Async Test2")
        console.log(all_recipe);
        return res.status(200).json(all_recipe);
```

Debug Console Out:

```
Async Test2
[]
GET /store/ABC%20Pizza%20Store/getAllMenu 200 179.642 ms - 2
Async Test1
Async Test1
Async Test1
```

**Solution**
Added Async/Await for Promise:

```
storeSchema.findOne(req.params,"chefs").exec()
.then(async result=>{
    if(result.length<1)
    {

        return res.status(409).json({
            error_code:20,
            message:"Store not registered by Manager yet"
        });
    }
    else
    {

        let all_recipe= []
        for(let i =0; i<result.chefs.email.length; ++i)
        {
            try{


                let recipes = await chefSchema['chef'].findOne({"email":result.chefs.email[i]},"recipe").exec();
                if(recipes!=null)
                {

                    if(recipes.recipe.length!=0)
                    {
                        all_recipe.push(recipes.recipe);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch(err)
            {
                return res.status(500).json({
                message:"getAllMenu Database Error!"
                });
            }

        }
        console.log("Async Test2")
        console.log(all_recipe);
        return res.status(200).json(all_recipe);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on of the alternatives would be to introduce the keyword `await` before logging your result to the console. It will literally make JavaScript wait until the promise returned by  `findOne` settles and returns its result.

use this [link](https://javascript.info/async-await) for refference.

I think the following should work:

```
let all_recipe= []
    for(let i =0; i<result.chefs.email.length; ++i)
    {

        await chefSchema['chef'].findOne({"email":result.chefs.email[i]},"recipe")
        .then(recipes=>{
            if(recipes!=null)
            {

                if(recipes.recipe.length!=0)
                {
                    all_recipe.push(recipes.recipe);
                }

            }
                        console.log("Async Test1")
        }).catch(err=>
        {

            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).json({
                message:"Finding Chef Database Error!",
                error: err
            });
        });

    }
    console.log("Async Test2")
    console.log(all_recipe);
    return res.status(200).json(all_recipe);
```